# should FragmentPagerAdapter keep a List<Fragment>?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I've read several examples of `FragmentPagerAdapter` in order to create swipe views. Now I have stopped cause I can't really decide which implementation is better:

First: We keep a `List<Fragment>` object as an attribute

```
public class PageAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    List<Fragment> list;

    public PageAdapter(FragmentManager fm, List<Fragment> list) {
        super(fm);
        this.list = list;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return list.get(position);
```

Second: We create fragments on the go

```
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch(position) {
            case 0: return FragmentA.newInstance(); break;
            case 1: return FragmentB.newInstance(); break;
```

which approach should be taken in a certain situation and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google recommends using the newInstance way like they do in their example: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentPagerAdapter.html

But still this is opinion based question and personally I suggest to do it Google way.

If you would be passing arguments to the `Fragment` and the arguments might change, then the newInstance way works, but not the already instantiated way with old arguments.